# click element if it exists in capybara

Tags: capybara

I wish to click a popup message that appears on my test app if it is present. I am new to capybara and cant seem to find a way to do this. I have previous experience with watir and if I were doing it with watir it would be something like:

```
if browser.link(:text, "name").exists? do
   browser.link(:text, "name").click
end
```

How can I do the same in capybara? Note this link will not always appear hence why I wish to have the if statement.

Comment: If you're writing a deterministic test shouldn't you *know* if that popup is going to exist or not?  Why are you checking for existence first instead of just going straight for the click?

Comment: @nzifnab because if element doesn't exist `click` method will fail

Comment: @Andrey But because you're writing a *test* you should KNOW if the element should be there or not.  Therefore, the click method SHOULD fail, because your test expectation is failing.  No?

Comment: @nzifnab OP specifically said that he wants to click a link only if it exists. There may be different reasons why OP wants it (SUT practices A/B testing, OP doesn't test his application, etc.)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like:

```
if page.find('.id') do 
   click_link('Some Link') # or page.find('.id').click
else 
   page.should_not have_selector('.id') # or something like that
end
```

Comment: @user1523236 if there is no element matching such selector `find` will throw a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` exception. So if link doesn't exist this code won't work

Comment: link = first(' ') has 'find' within it, it just finds the first link...if whatever is passed into find doesn't exist, it will throw the same exception.

Comment: @WhitneyImura `first` doesn't invoke `find` inside it. Look at the source code of [`first`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb#L143) and [`find`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb#L28)

Comment: Right. I see that now.  But I still don't agree with you regarding  how first is a better option than find.  What if the link no longer becomes the "first" one when the code changes?  Now, you're going to navigate somewhere, but it may (or may not) be the right link. Idk, just doesn't seem like it's any better, but I guess that's why we all have our personal preferences :)

Comment: @WhitneyImura what's true is that your code doesn't meet requirements that were specified by OP: he wanted to click link if it's present. Your code throws an exception if an element isn't present. Also I'd probably use `has_link?`/`click_link` in this situation as you can see in my edited answer (I made edits before you posted your last comment).

Answer (score 32):

A straight of the head code is to just invoke a [has_link?](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_link%3F-instance_method) matcher and then [click_link](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_link-instance_method) action:

```
if page.has_link?('name')
  page.click_link('name')
end
```

But it will be not the fastest solution as Capybara will make two queries to driver to get element: first one in `has_link?` and the second one in `click_link`.

A better variant may be to make only one query to get an element:

```
# This code doesn't check that an element exists only at one place and just chooses the first one
link = first('name')
link.click if link
```

or

```
# This code checks that element exists only at one place
links = all('name')
unless links.empty?
  links.count.should == 1
  link = links.first
  link.click
end
```

Personally I would go with `has_link?`/`click_link` implementation as the second variant does't check that element exists only at one place and the third one is too long.

Comment: This worked for me

          `click_link('whatever') if page.has_link?('whatever')`

Comment: `if ... do` creates syntax error (at least on ruby 2.3.1), removing `do` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 13):

In case I used `has_css?` query :

```
if page.has_css?("button #popUpButton") 
    click_button(#popUpButton")
end
```

Comment: this is too slow...find is the fastest, but cant be implemented as a condition

Answer (score 2):

You can use [first](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders:first), with option `minimum: 0`

```
item = first ".dropdown-item", minimum: 0
item.click if item&.visible?
```